# How to explode spaces from the index value of an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I am passing an array via `$_POST` method. I want to eliminate the spaces from the index values. My array is

```
Array
(
    [full_word] => hi there
    [btn] => 
)
```

I want to eliminate the space from the index element of `full_word` so that I can get the array below:

```
Array (
  [0]=> hi
  [1]=> there
)
```

But explode function is not working in here as `$_POST` returns an array and `explode` simply doesn't work on arrays.

What's the solution?

Comment: loop your array and then explode each `full word`

Answer (score 2):

You can `explode()` around `" "` using `array_walk`. Eg below:

```
$arr = [ "full_word" => "hi there", "btn" => "" ];

// explode each value of array around " "
array_walk($arr, function(&$v) {
    $v = explode(" ", $v);
});

print_r($arr); 
// Array ( [full_word] => Array ( [0] => hi [1] => there ) [btn] => Array ( [0] => d ) )
```

Read more:

- [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)
- [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to explode only 'full_word' section of $_POST array,

$full_word_array = explode(" ",$_POST['full_word']);
var_dump($full_word_array);

Answer (score 0):

Actually, @AniketSahrawat answer is perfectly OK, but if you want to maintain immutability, you can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$result = array_map(function ($item) {
    return strpos($item, ' ') === false
        ? $item
        : explode(' ', $item);    
}, $array);
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0be6e1584151a1a32aaacdc07070532c365deaec).